# Counting invalid values per row based on list of valid values per column (R)

Tags: r, list, lookup, purrr, counting

I am looking for a quick method to count invalid values per row. Here is a data frame as an example:

```
data <- data.frame("c1" = c(1,1,3,0,2,2,3,1,2,9),
                   "c2" = c(2,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,1,2),
                   "c3" = c(2,3,3,4,3,3,3,3,2,9),
                   "c4" = c(4,4,0,0,1,0,3,0,3,9),
                   "c5" = c(9,1,2,3,2,1,2,3,2,1))
```

I would like to have an additional numeric column that shows me per case how many of the values do not correspond to valid values defined in a list. For example, this list could look like this:

```
valid <- list("c1" = c(1:4,9),
              "c2" = c(1:3,9),
              "c3" = c(2:4,9),
              "c4" = c(0:3,9),
              "c5" = c(1:3,9))
```

So the column I am looking for in this example would be:

```
data$invalid <- c(1,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

I would prefer a tidyverse solution. I tried a bit with the different purrr::map functions, but unfortunately could not find any working solution. I thank you in advance for any helpful hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use `Map`

```
data$invalid <- unlist(Map(function(x, y) 
          sum(!x %in% y), data, valid[names(data)]))
```

---

Or with `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
imap_int(data, ~  sum(!.x %in% valid[[.y]])) %>%
    mutate(data, invalid = .)
```

#### Update

Based on the updated post

```
data$invalid <- Reduce(`+`, lapply(names(valid), 
  function(nm) Reduce(`&`, lapply(valid[[nm]], function(x) data[[nm]] != x))))
```

Comment: Thank you for your very fast response akrun. Unfortunately, after applying this solution to a much larger data frame this morning (i guess it's late night for you), I realized that it only works if the amounts of rows and columns are the same. My actual df has ten thousands of rows and a few dozen columns (identical with the number of objects in the list). Hence, I altered the example data frame.